# Which slots are proper to install 2x8GB of RAM?

Tags: memory, motherboard

Take a look at the image from the manual of the motherbors (Asus h87-e).

[image]

Am I supposed to install 2x8GB RAM modules into A1&A2 or into A1&B1?

Thanks!

Comment: ASUS? It's probably color coded, use the same color.

Comment: @Raystafarian Yes, A1&B1 are of the same color. So modules should go  to A1 and B1?

Comment: Yes, A1 and B1 is where you should put dual channel

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should populate A1 and B1 first. You can also use the coloring scheme of the DIMM slots:

[image]

Notice A1 and B1 are the same color? By installing the RAMs there you will enable the [dual-channel architecture](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-dual-triple-and-quad-channel-memory-architectures/).

Answer (score 5):

> Due to Intel Lynnfield CPU integrated memory controller limitation, DIMM slots A1 AND B1 must be populated first, or your system may not boot up, since the memory modules in A2 and B2 will not be recognized.

[ASUSTeK Computer Inc. -Support- FAQ](http://support.asus.com/FAQ/detail.aspx?no=89BB904F-C597-EE76-36CD-E0EDCD6CDD00)

> Letter commonly refer to channel, numbers commonly refer to order inside channel. 
>   In usual case (when manual doesn’t have other explicit instructions) slots must be 
>   filled in following order
>
> First slot of first channel (A1 in example)
>   First slot of second channel (B1)

[How to correctly install computer memory](http://rarst.net/hardware/install-memory)

> The memory modules are installed into matching banks, which are usually color-coded on the motherboard.

[§ Dual-channel architecture](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-channel_memory_architecture#Dual-channel_architecture)

Comment: It's very misleading, just had the same conundrum with ASUS, the manual says A1/A2 should match, while the colour coding indicates A1&B1 should match.

Comment: @Rudu, the manual for H97M-E also have the same error, it is indicating A1 and A2 should match to get dual channel.. but CPU-Z indicates otherwise..

Comment: ..and I do not understand why H87M-E is color coded but H97M-E isn't... one would reasonably think H97M-E is superior to H87M-E.., no?

Answer (score 1):

You want the same amount of memory on each controller channel, therefore A1 and B1 should be populated.