# Why does CPU-Z say the channel number is "single?"

Tags: memory

When I use CPU-Z it lists the DRAM frequency much lower then it is supposed to be, and says "channel # single"
does this mean it's running in single-channel mode instead of dual?

Also in memtest while it doesn't list any errors it sees the RAM as an even lower speed, and as DDR2 instead of 3. are these programs misdetecting the hardware or is there a serious problem with the RAM modules?

Comment: How low does CPU-Z list the RAM frequency? Like, half of the actual frequency? Are you saying that memtest says DDR2 and CPU-Z says its DDR3 ?

Comment: unless I'm reading it wrong it says 877Mhz. there's a different value that says "nb frequency" that's at 1449.7Mhz, but I don't know what NB means.

Comment: Is it on Memory tab or SPD tab? What does it say on SPD tab?

Comment: that's the memory tab. in the SPD tab for both modules anything referring to speed is in the 800-900 MHZ range.

Comment: With all DDR RAM, the effective transfer rate is twice the frequency. If it's, say, DDR3-1600 RAM, the frequency should be 800MHz.

Answer (score 8):

When you buy a RAM module (say DDR3-1600 MHz), you buy a memory module that has a theoretical speed of 800 MHz. That's the way it is, when you are buying, the naming has the value which is double the actual operating frequency. The reason behind this is the RAM being [DDR: Double Data Rate](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-ddr-ddr2-and-ddr3-memories/). They transfer two chunks of data in one clock cycle.

Now knowing that you have a theoretical speed of 800 MHz, you should also keep in mind that it is *theoretical*, not practical.

[image]

Take my DDR3-1600 MHz RAM for example, it has a 800 MHz theoretical frequency (which you can see on SPD tab) and it actually operates on 532.1 MHz.

There is also another issue about RAMs when the modules installed on your system are not operating at the same frequency. The RAM operating on lowest frequency determines the bus speed for CPU-RAM communication. So if you install a, say DDR3-1033 MHz RAM beside your DDR3-1600 MHz RAM, the bus will adjust to the 1033 MHz one. Thus, it will not be optimal for the DDR3-1600 MHz RAM. In addition, the system won't be able to use [Dual-Channel architecture](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-dual-triple-and-quad-channel-memory-architectures/) and your CPU-Z program will display Channel # as Single, not Dual. This is the reason you should choose identical RAMs for your system.

## Edit

I have looked up your motherboard's manual.

[image]

It states that you should first populate the black-color-coded slots first. So installing the modules on DIMM1 and DIMM3 (blue slots) may have caused your problems.

[image]

Comment: that's odd, as the readings for both RAM modules are the same. they came from a 4GB "kit" that consisted of 2 2GB DDR3 modules. if they weren't identical, the definitely should have been

Comment: Did you install them on laptop or desktop? If it's the desktop case, you should see [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/691707/279815), you may have an answer there if it's the case that you are installing your RAMs on different channels.

Comment: both modules are seated in Blue sockets- should I try moving them to black ones instead? (sockets from left to right: Blue,Black,Blue,Black)

Comment: You may try that and see how it goes. What's your motherboard?

Comment: FM2-A85XA-G43 (AMD A8-6600K)

Comment: Have you checked the [supported memory modules](http://www.msi.com/product/mb/FM2-A85XA-G43.html#/?div=MEMSupport) ?

Comment: @ZCoder please see my edit.

Comment: ahhh thanks! it might be the RAM model, but I'll try this first.